# Subdomain reverse proxy with nginx

Tags: networking, server, proxy, nginx

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy so I can access my different servers from outside my nat. My /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf looks like

```
server {
        listen  80;

        server_name torrent.website.org www.torrent.website.org;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/torrent_website_com_access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/pp_website_com_error/log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.16/;
        }
}
```

The dns is pointing at the correct address but it doesn't seem to be forwarding properly. I've tried with open port 80 on UFW and UFW disabled completely. I feel like I'm missing something obviose but I'm not sure what. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your backend servers are listening to a server name instead of IP.
Try this

```
 location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.16/;
  }
```